# Alternative proof to Hartshorne exercise IV.3.9. Is it correct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, algebraic-curves

This exercise asks you to prove:

> If $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a smooth curve of degree $d$, not in any plane, then for almost every hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{P}^3$, $H \cap X$ intersects $X$ exactly $d$ times.

By 'almost every', I mean an open subset of $(\mathbb{P}^3)^*$. A [previous solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599382/hartshorne-iv-3-9-to-prove-a-lemma-of-bertini-regarding-degree-d-curves-in-m) to this problem already exists here, but I think I've found a more quick solution which may be too good to be true, or cheating. There is another part to this problem which is not addressed in my proof.

**Proof:** By Bertini's theorem, the scheme theoretic intersection $X \cap H$ is nonsingular $0$-dimensional scheme for almost every hyperplane $H$. In particular, it will be a reduced scheme. On the other hand, $$d = \deg X \cap H = \sum_{P \in X \cap H} i(X, H; P) $$ by theorem I.7.7, and $i(X, H; P) = \dim_k( \mathcal{O}_{X \cap H, P})$ by the definition in that chapter. Now, if #$(X \cap H) < d$ then at least one $i(X, H; P) > 1$, which implies that $\dim _k (\mathcal{O}_{{X \cap H}, P}) > 1$ which cannot be for reduced, zero-dimensional, local rings (which are fields). Hence, $X \cap H$ is nonsingular if and only if it consists of $d$ distinct points, so we're done.

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you missed the point of the problem. The hard part is to show that no 3 of the $d$ points are collinear. Your argument seems fine to show that for a dense open set there are $d$ distinct points